# object.style.zoom property not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am using `object.style.zoom` for making zoom inside the div tag, it is working in IE. I need it for Firefox. Please guide me. Can I get any replacement for `style.zoom`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zoom` is not implemented in Firefox.

The "replacement" is [`transform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/) from CSS3: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/transform

A JavaScript example for Firefox:

```
document.getElementById('x').style.MozTransform = "scale(2)";
document.getElementById('x').style.MozTransformOrigin = "0 0";
```

It's worth pointing out that CSS3 transforms are [supported in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d). You should only be using `zoom` as a fallback for IE8 and lower.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working fine. But its going out of div tag. Can u help. Can i set top and left be 0.

Comment: Yes, you can adjust the [`transform-origin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-transform-origin). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your code for zoom is working without any disturb. I am try for object.runtimestyle.filter='Gray' for gray scale and object.runtimestyle.filter='Invert' for invert color. These things are working fine in IE, but firefox. Can u help for this.

Comment: Sure, but you should ask a new question. For those two, the answer isn't just a single line of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("myMainBody").style.transform = "scale(0.8)";
document.getElementById("myMainBody").style.transformOrigin = "0 0";
```

[**Given script shows unwanted "OPTIONS" panel in Firefox/Chrome browser**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGoEO.png)

The above script brings unwanted "OPTIONS" panel in Firefox/Chrome browser. I tested with Chrome too, this appears at chrome too (But we have an alternate in chrome, ie. style.zoom). Is there any way we can get rid of this OPTIONS panel in Firefox, which is shown when we use the above script?