# How can I make my website automatically zoom out to 90%

Tags: php, html, css, resize, zooming

I have a social netowork coded in PHP and css. Ive realized that it looks so much nicer and cleaner when its zoomed out at 90% instead of 100%. Is there a piece of code I can implement into the php or css to make the webpage automatically zoom out when its visited? This is mainly only for the login page.

if you want to take a look at the site, heres the URL: social.flamboyantent.co.uk

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load)

Comment: You can use the transform property, for inspiration and help see: http://css3generator.com

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you right.
This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function zoom() {
            document.body.style.zoom = "90%" 
        }
</script>

<body onload="zoom()">
```

To add zoom in Firefox read this [object.Style.Zoom property not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175766/object-style-zoom-property-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Thanks. It does work, but not with FireFox. How can I make this work on every browser?

Answer (score 3):

Last answer will work for major browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function zoom() {
        document.body.style.zoom = "90%" 
    }
```

This is the compatibility chart.

[image]

But as stated in [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css)

You could use the "proprietary" -moz-transform property in Firefox 3.5+.

So you could use:

```
div.zoomed { 
    zoom: 3; 
    -moz-transform: scale(3); 
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

And there´s also a BUGZILLA ticket.

[Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=390936)