# zoom in with Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I need to zoom in with Javascript(jQuery),

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + scrolling mouse.

I tried

```
document.body.style.zoom
```

but, it's not working in Firefox.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [object.Style.Zoom property not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175766/object-style-zoom-property-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom

Comment: Maybe CSS scale (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) would work. However, I am not sure if scaling an element will properly scale all its children elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of zoom do you exactly want to achieve, but maybe you should try to use **transform: scale(X);** with **transform-origin: 0 0;** and **max-width** set to a proportional value i.e.:

```
body {
   max-width: 50%;
   transform: scale(2);
   transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```