# Test zoom levels of page on browsers in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

To zoom in webpage on browser I searched solution and used following ways but I am receiving either an error or no zoom effect. Can someone please help me to identify where is the mistake or what's wrong with the code. Browser I am using is Chrome.

First method:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD));
```

> Error received on this: Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus
>   element

To solve above error I tried:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.tagname("html"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.click();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD);
actions.build().perform();
```

> Error received: unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on
>   'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Also I tried to replace element `html` with `body` but zoom not worked

Third way:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='80%'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested third way in chrome and IE browser, it was working fine.

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='200%'");
```

zoom is not implemented in Firefox.

The "replacement" is transform from CSS3: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/transform

**Below is the code for firefox browser:**

```
    WebDriver driver;    
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("document.body.style.MozTransform = 'scale(2)';");
```

Reference: [object.Style.Zoom property not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175766/object-style-zoom-property-not-working-in-firefox)

Let me know if you have any queries

Comment: thanks alot  these line of code helped me. It works.

Comment: @RabiaAsif, I Updated my answer please check it

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using [v̲e̲r̲s̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲3̲.̲3̲.̲1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.3/selenium-java-3.3.1.zip) of the Selenium Java Client Driver and [C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲D̲r̲i̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲2̲.̲2̲8](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/), the following works (where the number in single quotes represents the zoom level to use; 1 = 100%, 1.5 = 150%, etc.):

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '1.5'");
```

---

In addition, the zoom level in Firefox can be modified with the following:
1. The aforementioned Java Client Driver
2. [G̲e̲c̲k̲o̲D̲r̲i̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲v̲0̲.̲1̲5̲.̲0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.15.0)
3. These classes:
**java.awt.Robot**
**java.awt.event.KeyEvent**

First of all, instantiate the Robot class:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
```

This code causes the zoom level to *decrease*:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
```

This code causes the zoom level to *increase*:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
new Actions(driver)
     .sendKeys(Keys.Control).sendKeys(Keys.Add)
     .perform();
```

At list this works for me on C#.