# Firefox is not zoom in or out driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='100%'")

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I need some help with Firefox when I zoom in and out.
I'm using this function:

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='70%'")
```

It just works on Chrome. Does anyone know a solution for it?
I'm using python and selenium.

nothing is working in Firefox.
Chrome it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is an non-standard feature and Firefox doesn't have [zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom). The solution is suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7175800/2568849) as following:

```
document.getElementById('x').style.MozTransform = "scale(2)";
document.getElementById('x').style.MozTransformOrigin = "0 0";
```